# laravel queries in controller displays a variable

Tags: laravel, cart

Right now i'm working with Crinsane Laravel Shopping cart. I'm using 5.0

My problem is: I cant turn the variable into values, instead system display it as it is (variable) .

I want to know how exactly query database with specific column base on id , and turn then into values not variable it self .

My code :

```
public function addcart (){
    $products = Product::find(Input::get('id'));
    $qty = Input::get('qty');
    Cart::add('$products->id', 'products->name', $qty, $products->price, array('size' => 'large'));

    $cart_content = Cart::content();
    return view('pages.cart')->with('cart_content', $cart_content);
}
```

When run , it turn to display like this :

[image]

Comment: How you have your view. can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap `$products->id` and `$products->name` in quotes:

```php
Cart::add(
    $products->id,
    $products->name,
    $qty,
    $products->price,
    ['size' => 'large']
);
```

Comment: Thank you, another problem coming if i'm using return view ('product.cart',compact('Cart::content') then the cart content will be function but if i'm using return redirect ('product/cart') , then error : Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\newmarket\resources\views\pages\show.blade.php)